# How do I use aliases in a Union Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

The following query works without problem

```
SELECT [TblA].fieldA, 
iif(isnull([fieldA]),"",IIF(Len([fieldA]) - Len(Replace([fieldA], ",", ""))<1,[fieldA],Left([fieldA],InStr([fieldA],",")-1))) AS a, 
iif(isnull([fieldA]),"",IIF(Len([fieldA]) - Len(Replace([fieldA], ",", ""))<1,'',IIF(Len([fieldA]) - Len(Replace([fieldA], ",", ""))=1,Right([fieldA],len([fieldA])-len([a])-1),           Mid([fieldA],Len([a])+2,Instr(Len([a])+2,[fieldA],",")-Len([a])-2)))) AS b, 
iif(isnull([fieldA]),"",IIF(Len([fieldA]) - Len(Replace([fieldA], ",", ""))<2,'',IIF(Len([fieldA]) - Len(Replace([fieldA], ",", ""))=2,Right([fieldA],len([fieldA])-len([a])-len([b])-2),  Mid([fieldA],Len([a])+Len([b])+3,Instr(Len([a])+Len([b])+3,[fieldA],",")-Len([a])-Len([b])-3)))) AS c, 
iif(isnull([fieldA]),"",IIF(Len([fieldA]) - Len(Replace([fieldA], ",", ""))<3,'',IIF(Len([fieldA]) - Len(Replace([fieldA], ",", ""))=3,Right([fieldA],len([fieldA])-len([a])-len([b])-len([c])-3),  ""))) AS d
FROM TblA;
```

However, when I am trying to do the same in a Union Query it does not work ( `Enter Parameter Value` for `a` )

```
SELECT iif(isnull([fldA]),"",IIF(Len([fldA]) - Len(Replace([fldA], ",", ""))<1,[fldA],Left([fldA],InStr([fldA],",")-1))) AS a FROM tblA
UNION
SELECT iif(isnull([fldA]),"",IIF(Len([fldA]) - Len(Replace([fldA], ",", ""))<1,'',IIF(Len([fldA]) - Len(Replace([fldA], ",", ""))=1,Right([fldA],len([fldA])-len([a])-1),Mid([fldA],Len([a])+2,Instr(Len([a])+2,[fldA],",")-Len([a])-2)))) AS b FROM tblA
UNION
SELECT iif(isnull([fldA]),"",IIF(Len([fldA]) - Len(Replace([fldA], ",", ""))<2,'',IIF(Len([fldA]) - Len(Replace([fldA], ",", ""))=2,Right([fldA],len([fldA])-len([a])-len([b])-2),Mid([fldA],Len([a])+Len([b])+3,Instr(Len([a])+Len([b])+3,[fldA],",")-Len([a])-Len([b])-3)))) AS c FROM tblA
UNION
SELECT iif(isnull([fldA]),"",IIF(Len([fldA]) - Len(Replace([fldA], ",", ""))<3,'',IIF(Len([fldA]) - Len(Replace([fldA], ",", ""))=3,Right([fldA],len([fldA])-len([a])-len([b])-len([c])-3),  ""))) As d FROM tblA
```

**My question is:**
Is there a way to use aliases in Union queries (e.g. `As a` )

Comment: Look closely at the `AS b`  line in the union query.  It contains this: `id([fldA],Len([a])` and that is what causes Access to complain about "undefined function".  Perhaps it should have been `Mid()` instead of `id()`?

Comment: Thanks HansUp, that solved at least one problem. Now I get prompt `Enter Parameter Value` for `a`

Comment: Unfortunately I doubt Access will let you do `len([a])` in one select clause when `a` is an alias defined in another select clause of the union query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot reference field (alias or not) from one SELECT in another SELECT. These are not nested statements. Also, only the first SELECT defines field names. The subsequent AS clauses are ignored and can be removed.

Build the first query object where these calculations occur. Then build UNION with first query as source.

```
SELECT a AS Data, "A" AS Category FROM query
UNION SELECT b, "B" FROM query
UNION SELECT c, "C" FROM query
UNION SELECT d, "D" FROM query;
```

UNION will not allow duplicate rows. Use UNION ALL to include all records, even if there are duplicates.

Comment: Thanks June7, knowing that fields cannot be referenced from one SELECT in another SELECT, helped me a lot in this case and perhaps in other issues to come. I solved it by doing it according your suggestion.